# Como puedo pasar campos dinamicos de consulta mysql a ireport

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

Al hacer una consulta sql los campos varian y no sé como puedo hacer para que el ireport me muestre esos campos con sus datos cuando lo ejecute.
Eje: Consulta 1: SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM tabla; pero el reporte también puede recibir esta otra consulta SELECT col4, col5, col6 FROM tabla. Como hacer para que el ireport me cargue las columnas de la consulta sql

gracias.

Answer (score 1):

RESPUESTA: Lo que hice fue poner parametros en las columnas y ponerle un alias en la query. Ej: 
SELECT $P!{Columna} AS Columna,`$P!{fecha1}` AS fecha1,`$P!{fecha2}` AS fecha2,`$P!{fecha3}` AS fecha3, `$P!{fecha4}` AS fecha4, `$P!{fecha5}` AS fecha5 FROM $P!{tabla};

El la parte "fields" de la izquierda del Ireport cree los campos de cada parametro:
Columna, fecha1, fecha2 ... fecha5.

En la hoja del reporte solo asigne los fields a los textfields respectivos.
Arranqué el reporte, coloque los valores de los parametros y listo.

Espero les sea de ayuda. =D

Answer (score 0):

Debe aplicar justamente parámetros en ireport, que desde la misma interfaz se puede crear y tipar los que necesite, luego en tu consulta llamas como `$P{parametro}`

Comment: Ahora como muestro el contenido de cada columna en el ireport ?

Comment: Lo que deseas creo es como hacer un subreport ya que dentro de un reporte solo te acepta una query, pero con los subreports tu puedes hacer varias querys con el mismo poder como si fuera un reporte, incluso le puede pasar parametros.

Comment: Lo que deseo es que me muestre los campos de la query que le paso desde java. La query puede variar en las columnas (de 1 a 5). No las puedo fijar en el jasper debido a que son dinamicas (la query). Como hago para que el ireport me muestre las columnas de la query que le pase ??

Comment: Añade un subreporte por cada caso que tengas y un parámetro que lo identifique y que oculte el resto de subreportes.

Comment: Hola de nuevo. Ya lo resolví con parametros. Dejaré la respuesta por si alguién más a futuro necesita.